# Software to allow saves to external drive when it's not present?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm wondering if software for this purpose already exists.

What I want to be able to do is to be able to save to my external drive when it is not connected to my computer. By this I mean I want the drive to always appear as though it is connected so that I can choose to write to it whenever I want. If the drive is connected when I save to it the files I want to save will be written to my local drive and then when the external is connected, copied across.

Does anything similar to this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not in the form you want, but have you thought about using rsync via Terminal?

i.e., rsync –r /Users/you/Documents/ /your_network_mount/destination_folder/

Then either run it from the Terminal whenever you need to, or save the above as a .command, create an Automator workflow, and run the .command using "Do Shell Script". If you save the workflow as an Application, you can just double-click it and voilà.. instant directory syncing to your external drive at your fingertips.